# UILabel appears as "__NSCFString" in crash report (on iPad3 only)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm getting crash reports for an issue that only appears to be happening on a certain model of iPads (the iPad 3). Here's the error:

`NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFString setText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...`

And here's the section of code it's coming from—specifically, the third line below:

```
for thisColumn in 0..<numberOfColumns{
    let thisElement=ElementClass(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,0,0),column:thisColumn);
    thisElement.myLabel.text=elementText(thisColumn)
```

I don't have an iPad 3 to test on, and unfortunately the "iPad Retina" simulator doesn't recreate the issue. So, this is all I have to go on.

`ElementClass` is one of my app's custom classes, and it's a subclass of `UIControl`. One of its subviews is called `myLabel`, and it should be a `UILabel`. Because it appears as a `__NSCFString` in the crash, the problem may have to do with the `UILabel` setup. The `ElementClass` initializer sets up the `UILabel` by calling the following code:

```
let myLabel=UILabel()

private func setupMyLabel(){
    let thisLabel=myLabel;
    thisLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0,
                               underlineY+myImage.frame.size.height,
                               self.frame.size.width,
                               self.frame.size.height-underlineY)
    self.addSubview(thisLabel)
    // other styling
    return
}
```

And once again, this has only been happening (so far) on iPad 3s. Thanks for reading, any thoughts on what could be the problem would be terrific.

EDIT:

Here's the full init method of ElementClass:

```
init(frame: CGRect, column:Int) {
    // Setup general structure
    self.column=column;
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.frame.size.width=elementWidth;
    self.frame.size.height=ElementClass.elementHeight;
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

    setupMyLabel() 
    // other setup methods
}
```

Comment: Usually when you get an error where an object should be one type but it's another type instead, it's because it's a "zombie" (An object that was deallocated and freed, but somebody keeps a pointer to it.) Such things are less common using ARC, but still possible. We'd need to know a lot more about the lifecycle of this label object to help figure out what's going on with it.

Comment: @DuncanC  Thanks for the comment. As far as the lifecycle goes, the ElementClass initializer calls setupMyLabel() and I believe that's all that happens to myLabel by the time the thisElement.myLabel.text line of code is called. What other information would be helpful for me to provide? Let me know and I can add it to the question.

Comment: A nice occasion to test address sanitizer, isn't it ?

Comment: NSZombieEnabled is a good way to debug sending messages to deallocate objects